# chisel compilation error: object plugin is not a member of package chisel3.internal

Tags: scala, chisel

I am studying chisel3 with a small trial project.

I finished code, fixed several syntax issues in compilation, then, it reported an error without indicating error file and line number.

```
$ sbt test
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.9 (Red Hat, Inc. Java 1.8.0_292)
[info] loading settings for project fparser-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /mnt/disk1/yupeng/repos/fparser/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to fparser (in build file:/mnt/disk1/yupeng/repos/fparser/)
[info] compiling 3 Scala sources to /mnt/disk1/yupeng/repos/fparser/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] ## Exception when compiling 3 sources to /mnt/disk1/yupeng/repos/fparser/target/scala-2.12/classes
[error] scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: object plugin is not a member of package chisel3.internal
[error] 
[error]            
[error] scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: object plugin is not a member of package chisel3.internal
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: object plugin is not a member of package chisel3.internal
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jul 16, 2021 4:38:42 PM
```

what does it mean? please help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found, the error is gone after I changed chisel3 versions in build.sbt.

```
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.4.3",
//      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.2.6", // this one generate plugin error above
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.3.3" % "test",
      "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "rocketchip" % "1.2.6"
```

Previously I changed from 3.4.3 to 3.2.6 because sbt warning of

```
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
```

I ran sbt evicted and it said rocketchip 1.2.6 should use chisel3 3.2.6.

Maybe someone can clarify.

Comment: As you figured out, `chiseltest` 0.3 works with `chisel3` 3.4, see the docs page on versioning for more information and a table of compatible versions: https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/appendix/versioning.html. `rocketchip` is not actively published so 1.2.6 probably is only compatible with `chisel3` 3.2. My suggestion is to use chipyard which builds rocket-chip from source if you want up-to-date rocket-chip.